# Error in Android XML file saying "Android resource compilation failed"

Tags: java, android-studio

Could a kind soul please tell me what is wrong with my xml file? The problem seems to be line 19 but so I changed the wording but it didn't help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textChild"

        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"

        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:text="Child Item"/>
   </ LinearLayout>
```

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/ven/AndroidStudioProjects/myStat/app/src/
main/res/layout/child_item.xml","position":{"startLine":19}}],"original":"/Users/ven/AndroidStudioProjects/myStat/app/src/
main/res/layout/child_item.xml:20: 
AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed",
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the end tag for LinearLayout

Change `</ LinearLayout>` to `</LinearLayout>`

Remove the space :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the real problem, but I can't comment yet... there is a space in the closing tag of the LinearLayout maybe that's the problem